# Dispatch.main.asyncAfter() crash app when called before it's finished

Tags: ios, swift, crash

so I have an app with radiobuttons to check off tasks, everything's working as expected as long as I let the animation finish but if I press two buttons at the same time I get an error:

> libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

**The Code executed every time a radiobutton is tapped**

```
   func RadioTapped(_ cell: TableViewCell) {


    if let indexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: cell) {
        // Removes task from coreData
        let task = self.tasks[indexPath.row]
       print(tasks.count)
        self.context.delete(task)
        print(tasks.count)
        (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).saveContext()
        do{
            self.tasks = try self.context.fetch(TodayTask.fetchRequest())

            // Animates the removal of task cell
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .milliseconds(800),execute: {
                self.tableView.beginUpdates()
                self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
                self.tableView.endUpdates()
            })

        } catch {
            print("Fetching Failed")
        }
    }


}
```

**Error Message**

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (11) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (13), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 1 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'

Comment: Run it on the simulator for getting error log..

Comment: I ran it on the simulator but where do I find the log?

Comment: You need to show the message associated with the exception, it will tell you what went wrong, but I will say that `asyncAfter` is a code smell; you shouldn't need time delays

Comment: Paulw11 is right. Also try to move `self.tasks = try self.context.fetch(TodayTask.fetchRequest())' in main block and see.

Answer (score 0):

Table row delete operation also requires to delete element of array of table.

According to your code, `self.tasks` may be an array for your table list.

Delete an element of 'self.tasks' from same indexes, for which you are deleting your rows.

Hint:

```
// Remove array element
self.tasks.remove(at: <index.row>)


DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .milliseconds(800),execute: {
                self.tableView.beginUpdates()
                self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
                self.tableView.endUpdates()
            })
```

Comment: Clearly written that `self.context.delete(task)` and after this `self.tasks = try self.context.fetch(TodayTask.fetchRequest())`

Comment: Wont the self.context.delete(task) remove the task at indexPath?

Comment: @SalmanGhumsani Agree with you. its re-initiate array from context. but need to ensure, no. of elements of array exact before delete operation

Comment: When I print the tasks.count I get 13, 13 then 12 12

Comment: @J-Doe Pl. add your print statement in question, so I can help you better. Your error message says, delete operation is performed twice.

Comment: I updated the code in the main post to include the print message